How to Add Custom Tax Fields to WooCommerce Checkout and Address Pages (Gutenberg Block-Based)
I need to add two fields named "Tax Office" and "Tax Number" after the "Company Name" field in the billing information form on both the payment and addresses pages of my WooCommerce site.
The payment page is Gutenberg block-based. Therefore, I first created a JavaScript file named custom-checkout-fields.js with the following content:
// custom-checkout-fields.js
const initializeCheckoutBlocks = () => {
    // WooCommerce Blocks API check
    if (!window.wc || !window.wc.blocks || !window.wp) {
        console.log('WooCommerce Blocks API could not be loaded');
        return;
    }

    const { registerCheckoutBlock } = window.wc.blocks;
    const { createElement } = window.wp.element;
    const { TextControl } = window.wp.components;
    
    // Tax fields component
    const TaxFields = () => {
        return createElement('div', { className: 'wc-block-checkout__tax-fields' },
            [
                createElement(TextControl, {
                    key: 'tax-office',
                    label: 'Tax Office',
                    required: true,
                    className: 'tax-office-field'
                }),
                createElement(TextControl, {
                    key: 'tax-number',
                    label: 'Tax Number',
                    required: true,
                    className: 'tax-number-field'
                })
            ]
        );
    };

    // Register block
    registerCheckoutBlock({
        metadata: {
            name: 'tax-fields-block',
            parent: ['woocommerce/checkout-billing-address-block'],
        },
        component: TaxFields
    });
};

// Run when page is loaded
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initializeCheckoutBlocks);
} else {
    initializeCheckoutBlocks();
}

// Check when WooCommerce Blocks are ready
document.addEventListener('wc-blocks-is-ready', initializeCheckoutBlocks);

In functions.php, I added the following code:
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_meta('shop_order', '_billing_tax_office', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
    ]);
    
    register_post_meta('shop_order', '_billing_tax_number', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
    ]);
});

// Add fields to Store API
add_action('woocommerce_blocks_checkout_update_order_meta', function($order) {
    if (!empty($_POST['tax_office'])) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_tax_office', sanitize_text_field($_POST['tax_office']));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['tax_number'])) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_tax_number', sanitize_text_field($_POST['tax_number']));
    }
});

To add the fields to the form on the addresses page, I used the following code:
// Add tax fields to checkout page
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_tax_fields_to_checkout');

function add_tax_fields_to_checkout($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_tax_office'] = array(
        'label' => 'Tax Office',
        'placeholder' => 'Enter your Tax Office',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear' => true,
        'priority' => 120
    );
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_tax_number'] = array(
        'label' => 'Tax Number',
        'placeholder' => 'Enter your Tax Number',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear' => true,
        'priority' => 121
    );
    
    return $fields;
}

// Save tax fields in the order
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_tax_fields');

function save_tax_fields($order_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['billing_tax_office'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_tax_office', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_tax_office']));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['billing_tax_number'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_tax_number', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_tax_number']));
    }
}

// Show tax fields in admin panel order details
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'show_tax_fields_in_admin');

function show_tax_fields_in_admin($order) {
    echo '<p><strong>Tax Office:</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_billing_tax_office', true) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Tax Number:</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_billing_tax_number', true) . '</p>';
}

However, the fields do not appear on either form.

For customizing fields for checkout blocks, see this documentation, but it's complicated and limited. Note that Checkout Blocks only allow very few customizations. Also, as now HPOS is enabled, don't use WordPress Post meta, as WooCommerce uses custom database tables.

I couldn't solve the problem, so I purchased the Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce plugin.
